# Python unittest, how to display a better group/test name?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Using Python Unittest, here's an example of a test suite :

```
import unittest

# Here's our "unit".
def IsOdd(n):
    return n % 2 == 1

# Here's our "unit tests".
class IsOddTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def testOne(self):
        self.failUnless(IsOdd(1))

    def testTwo(self):
        self.failIf(IsOdd(2))

def main():
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the result :

```
testOne (__main__.IsOddTests) ... ok
testTwo (__main__.IsOddTests) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Is it possible to enhance the display of the tests, something like :

```
Testing ODD method
Testing with value is 1 (__main__.IsOddTests) ... ok
Testing with value is 2 (__main__.IsOddTests) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

What I'm trying to do, is in case of a lot of tests, displaying a Group name for each TestCase (that contains multiple tests), and a name for each tests (that should be more explicit than just the function name).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this simply set a docstring for your tests:

```
def testOne(self):
    """Test IsOdd(1)"""
    self.failUnless(IsOdd(1))

def testTwo(self):
    """Test IsOdd(2)"""
    self.failIf(IsOdd(2))
```

There's a bit of an art to picking docstrings for your tests that will make sense later.  Don't be afraid to go back and refactor your things.

Comment: Awesome for naming my tests, and for my classes now, I tried the docstring too, but without any luck. Any idea?

Comment: I don't believe that `unittest.py` uses the docstring from the class anywhere, at least in the versions I've checked.  (Look for \_\_doc\_\_ in the .py file).

Comment: I made my own. I added a `__display__` in each class, and in a root class, I look for this var and display it in `setUpClass` ;)